# Facebook Matching API - Page Scoped ID (PSID) empty for other users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a bunch of users registred on my website thanks to `Laravel Socialite` and `Facebook Login`. When a user creates a account their `app_scoped_id` is save under `provider_user_id`.

I need to get the `page_scoped_id` of a user on my page instead of `app_scoped_id`.

To do so I am using the `Facebook Matching ID` whose documentation could be find [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching/)

#### The code

```
$fb = new Facebook(...);

$response = $fb->get($user->socialAccount->provider_user_id . '/ids_for_pages?fields=id&page=' . env('FB_PAGE_ID'), env('FACEBOOK_PAGE_TOKEN'));
$pageScopedId = $response->getDecodedBody()['data'][0]['id'];
```

#### Issue

It works perfectly for myself, but when I'm trying to get other users' page scoped id, it returns an empty array.

Comment: You have app and page associated with the same business, I assume? Did you also note what the documentation says, that the initial API call might trigger a review of the app?

Comment: I did associate the page and the app within the same business. I also note that but what does it means ? It has been 2 days I’m testing this API and doing several calls with my user id. Do I need specific permissions ? Is there a way I can test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook Matching API is able to match page scoped id and app-scoped id if and only if they both exist.

In my case, page scoped id has not been associated with users (since they have not interacted with the messenger yet).